# python get-pip.py --root -bash: $'python\302\240get-pip.py': command not found

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip part of my automation process and I get the below error

$ python get-pip.py --root
-bash: $'python\302\240get-pip.py': command not found

Link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html#awscli-install-linux-pip

I followed the above link, which worked previously and doesn't work now.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be copying and pasting something that isn't a space. Try typing out the command manually.

Comment: Do you have python installed already? Can you do `python` in a terminal and have the interpreter start at all?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Yes, I have python already installed.. I added all the steps part of my bootstrap script and it started working... Sometimes these tools are little weird and scary

Comment: Have you addressed @DanielRoseman 's comment? I did not pay attention but the `\302\240` that show in the error are erroneous. Did you try to type the command without copy-pasting?